# Animate Translate View to edge of screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I was trying to Animate View from its location to the edge of the screen , and `100%p` was getting the view out of the screen,

[image: required animation]

the image describe the required animation, for anyone asking for the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html):

> android:toXDelta
>
> Float or percentage. Ending X **offset**. Expressed either: in pixels relative to the normal position (such as "5"), in percentage **relative to the element width** (such as "5%"), or in percentage **relative to the parent width** (such as "5%p").

Assuming your button width is 20% of it's parent width, you must specify your toXDelta as

`50%p-(20%p/2) = 40%p`

The problem with this solution is that you probably don't know the button width in terms of "% of it's parent width" (not sure since you didn't post the xml). So I would suggest to define your animation programmatically.